# Moodle - Using "Old code" when I am actually using the newest version

Tags: moodle

I have had too many problems with my ubuntu moodle server, so now tried to do a factory resetting of my server and install everything anew. Even though I checked out with the newest git repo available, I am still getting the following error message:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNWwM.jpg

The branch I checked out with was 'origin/MOODLE_400_STABLE'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself :) Can you please copy and paste the text when asking a question rather than an image, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the `value` for `version` in your database

```
SELECT value
FROM mdl_config
WHERE name = 'version'
```

Then search for the value in the releases, this will tell you which version the database is using

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Releases

You might need to do a `git pull` for the latest version of Moodle 4